# InvalidCastException when binding a Xamarin ListView to an IEnumerable<Person>

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have this ListView in a Xamarin app:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Person.All}" x:Name="list">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And I'm trying to bind it to an `IEnumerable<Person>` by setting the `ItemsSource` property to the new enumerable. (Yes, I know I should create a viewmodel, but I hate MVVM with a passion!) But when there is data in the enumerable, I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

This does not happen immediately after setting `ItemsSource`; I have a try/catch block containing the set operation, but no exception is caught. Rather it happens as soon as I get out of the method where I'm setting the `ItemsSource`. There is no stack trace associated with this error; that's all I get apart from some generic "Unhandled Exception" message.

Here is the method where I am setting the `ItemsSource`:

```
private void BtnLogIn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // log in
        var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp($"http://{Configuration.Hostname}/api/login?systemID=1091&login={txtLogin.Text}&password={txtPassword.Text}");
        var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        var cookiesData = resp.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie");
        var regex = new Regex($@"{CookieManager.LoginCookieID}=(.*); expires=.*");
        Login.CookieValue = regex.Match(cookiesData).Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
        list.ItemsSource = Person.All; // reload person list
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
    }
}
```

(yes I know putting a password in a URL is a bad idea; this is just a proof of concept!)

And here is the `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public static IEnumerable<Person> All => GetWebData<IEnumerable<Person>>($"http://{Configuration.Hostname}/api/people", CookieManager.LoginCookieID, Login.CookieValue);

    private static T GetWebData<T>(string url, string cookieKey, string cookieValue)
    {
        try
        {
            var web = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            web.Headers["Set-Cookie"] = $"{cookieKey}={cookieValue}";
            var stream = web.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            T data;
            var json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            try
            {
                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            }
            catch
            {
                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(json).Single();
            }
            return data;
        }
        catch
        {
            // could not access data, maybe not logged in yet?
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Name => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out - looks like `<Label Text="{Binding Name}" />` is not valid as a DataTemplate; I changed the `Label` to a `TextCell` and everything works!